# Encrypted Bluetooth chat communication

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth

Having issues with the app, shuts down any time I click on the chat button. I just submitted my manifest, gradle , xml, and the mainactivity to check what really went wrong. Thanks

```
I have an error from the logcat 
GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1. 
2021-06-26 05:10:29.573 24952-24952/c.bawp.securemessenger D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-26 05:10:29.587 24952-24952/c.bawp.securemessenger E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: c.bawp.securemessenger, PID: 24952
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {c.bawp.securemessenger/c.bawp.securemessenger.ChatController}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:574)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:560)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4905)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4873)
        at c.bawp.securemessenger.ChooseActivity$1.onClick(ChooseActivity.java:26)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2021-06-26 05:10:29.657 24952-24952/c.bawp.securemessenger I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24952 SIG: 9
```

So I don't know if this is the reason why it keeps shutting down any time I tap the button chat. The button chat is created in an activity.xml.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="c.bawp.securemessenger">
        
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        
        
            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@drawable/icon"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
                android:theme="@style/Theme.SecureMessenger">
                <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
                <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
                <activity android:name=".ChooseActivity" >
        
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
        
                <activity android:name=".FileExchangeActivity"></activity>
            </application>
        
        </manifest>
```

```java
    package c.bawp.securemessenger;
    
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
            private TextView status;
            private Button btnConnect;
            private ListView listView;
            private Dialog dialog;
            private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
            private MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
        private ArrayAdapter<String> chatAdapter;
        private ArrayList<String> chatMessages;
    
            private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    
            public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
            public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
            public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
            public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT = 4;
            public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
            public static final String DEVICE_OBJECT =  "device_name";
    
            private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
            private ChatController chatController;
            private BluetoothDevice connectingDevice;
            private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevicesAdapter;
            private Encrypt encrypt;
    
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            findViewsByIds();
    
            //check device support bluetooth or not
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    
            //show bluetooth devices dialog when click connect button
            btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
    
                    showPrinterPickDialog();
                }
            });
    
            //set chat adapter
            messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
            listView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    
            encrypt = new Encrypt();
        }
    
        private final Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                        switch (msg.arg1) {
                            case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED:
                                setStatus("Connected to: " + connectingDevice.getName());
                                btnConnect.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                break;
                            case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTING:
                                setStatus("Connecting...");
                                //btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                                break;
                            case ChatController.STATE_LISTEN:
                            case ChatController.STATE_NONE:
                                setStatus("Not connected");
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
    
                    case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                        byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
    
                        String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                        writeMessage = encrypt.decrypt(writeMessage);
                        //check out
                        MemberData data1 = new MemberData("Me","#C62828");
                        c.bawp.securemessenger.Message message1 = new c.bawp.securemessenger.Message(writeMessage, data1, true);
                        messageAdapter.add(message1);
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_READ:
                        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
    
                        String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                        readMessage = encrypt.decrypt(readMessage);
                        MemberData data2 = new MemberData(connectingDevice.getName(),"#C62828");
                        Log.d("Bug", "handleMessage: " + readMessage);
                        c.bawp.securemessenger.Message message2 = new c.bawp.securemessenger.Message(readMessage, data2, false);
                        messageAdapter.add(message2);
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT:
                        connectingDevice = msg.getData().getParcelable(DEVICE_OBJECT);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectingDevice.getName(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString("toast"),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    
        private void showPrinterPickDialog() {
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bluetooth);
            dialog.setTitle("Bluetooth Devices");
    
    
            if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            }
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    
            //Initializing bluetooth adapters
            ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            discoveredDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    
            //locate listviews and attach the adapters
            ListView listView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
            ListView listView2 = dialog.findViewById(R.id.discoveredDeviceList);
            listView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesAdapter);
            listView2.setAdapter(discoveredDevicesAdapter);
    
            // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    
            filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
            filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
            registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);
    
            // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    
    
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    
            // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                    pairedDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            } else {
                pairedDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_paired));
            }
    
            //Handling listview item click event
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
    
                    connectToDevice(address);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
    
            });
    
            listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                    String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
    
                    connectToDevice(address);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    
            dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }
    
    
        private void setStatus(String s) {
    
            status.setText(s);
        }
    
        private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
            chatController.connect(device);
        }
    
    
        private void findViewsByIds() {
    
            status = findViewById(R.id.status);
            btnConnect = findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
            listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
            inputLayout = findViewById(R.id.input_layout);
            Button btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
    
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (Objects.requireNonNull(inputLayout.getEditText()).getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        //TODO: here
                        sendMessage(inputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
                        inputLayout.getEditText().setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth still disabled, turn off application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    
        private void sendMessage(String message) {
            if (chatController.getState() != ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connection was lost!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
    
            if (message.length() > 0) {
                message = encrypt.encrypt(message);
                byte[] send = message.getBytes();
                chatController.write(send);
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    
    
                Intent dIntent =  new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                dIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 3000);
                startActivity(dIntent);
    
            } else {
                chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
            }
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
    
            if (chatController != null) {
                if (chatController.getState() == ChatController.STATE_NONE) {
                    chatController.start();
                }
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (chatController != null)
                chatController.stop();
        }
    
        private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
    
                // When discovery finds a device
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                    if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    }
                    // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
                } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                    discoveredDevicesAdapter.clear();
                    //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                    // setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    
                    setTitle("Select a device to connect");
                    if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
    
                        discoveredDevicesAdapter.add("No devices found");
                    }
                } else {
                    discoveredDevicesAdapter.add("Scanning Bluetooth Devices....");
                }
            }
    
    
        };
    
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It usually helps if you build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This way, people will be able to better understand and answer your question -- and most of the time, you will be able to figure out how to fix your problem yourself during the process.

Comment: *android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {**c.bawp.securemessenger/c.bawp.securemessenger.ChatController**}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)*